# Can I replace the "#" sign in a subversion url so it can be accessed through http?

Tags: svn, http, httpwebrequest

Some of the people in my office create subfolders in their subversion projects with a `#` sign. Such as:

```
https://subversion/Repo/Product/tags/version/Source/c#/FTP/bin/
```

Subversion and TortoiseSVN don't have any problem with that, but when I navigate to that using a browser (or more specifically, `HttpWebRequest`) it dies because the `#` is not valid in a URL.

Is there some html code or something I can replace the `#` with in code so that I can pull the files from Subversion using http?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd just need to use the URL encoded value for `#` which is `%23`

```
https://subversion/Operations/iHealth/tags/1.9.002_diag/Source/c%23/FTP/bin/
```

http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

Answer (score 2):

The URL escape code for the `#` symbol is `%23`. So your URL should be like this:

```
https://subversion/Operations/iHealth/tags/1.9.002_diag/Source/c%23/FTP/bin/
```

Also here is a page with all the other codes: http://www.december.com/html/spec/esccodes.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are already using HttpWebRequest:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
    HttpUtility.UrlEncode(
      "https://subversion/Operations/iHealth/tags/1.9.002_diag/Source/c#/FTP/bin/"));
```

Comment: Oddly, when I added HttpUtility.UrlEncode I got an error "Invalid Uri."